# Problem with orthogonalizing the Laguerre polynomials

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials, gram-schmidt, function-spaces, laguerre-polynomials

Alright, so I ran into a little problem while applying the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process. To the functions $\{1,x,x^2,x^3...\}$ over $x\in(0,\infty)$ with weight function $\sigma (x)=e^{-x}$. As a reminder:

$$<x^n,x^m>=\int_0^{\infty}x^n x^m e^{-x}dx=(n+m)!$$

The first three polynomials I obtained were:
\begin{align}
\phi_0 &=1\\
\phi_1 &=x-1\\
\phi_2 &=x^2-4x-2
\end{align}

It's very strange to me that $\phi_2$ is orthogonal to $\phi_1$, but NOT orthogonal to $\phi_0$. Note that $\phi_1$ and $\phi_0$ are not only orthogonal to one another, but also each already normalized. Using these two for the orthogonalization process, you get $\phi_2$... Why is this happening?

Comment: Try $+2$ instead of $-2$ ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#The_first_few_polynomials

Comment: I just figured it out. I kept doing the computation and multiplying the value of my integral for orthogonality between $\phi_1$ by $x$ instead of $x-1$. I'm going to provide an answer for my question and make a PSA to always do things correctly the first time.

Comment: The Laguerre polynomials are orthogonal. Did you mean the monomials?